# Placing a yeoman project on github

Tags: github, yeoman

I used yeoman to bootstrap a Angular project. Once bootstrapped, I added a directive or two along with one new route. All works fine.

I now want to share this project with other developers in my team. So I guess I want to place it on Github.

What's the correct protocol to now move this to github ?

Do I run a Yeoman command or just some github command ?
Do I just have to upload the directory ?

Answer (score 0):

I simply removed all lines from .gitignore and performed the usual git add and git commit on the project.